# Proxy support in MSAL for ObjectiveC on Mac

Tags: objective-c, azure-ad-msal

MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) for .NET has proxy support using HttpClientFactory. In HttpClientFactory implementation I can create HttpClient and provide proxy details, then that HttpClientFactory can be used while creating PublicClientApplication.

However, I couldn't find similar proxy support in MSAL for ObjectiveC. Please guide me with an example.

Comment: More information about question. Suppose on one machine I have configured a proxy server (e.g. using CCProxy or any other proxy server software) and on other machines I have updated network configuration to use this proxy server so that all the web requests from my other machines should go through the proxy server.

Comment: Now if I launch the authentication app created using MSAL & ObjectiveC then it should also honor the proxy settings. For that, I assume, I will have to pass the proxy server settings (server address, credentials etc.) to PublicClientApplication.

This is what I could do in authentication application created in .NET Classic & MSAL. I have to pass HttpClientFactory which creates HttpClient and provide proxy server details. I referred to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/httpclient

Comment: I was looking for similar support in MSAL for ObjectiveC. It would be great if there is similar link which could guide me to achieve proxy support in my ObjectiveC application. Thanks!

Comment: My query is resolved. MSAL support for ObjectiveC uses the default system proxy settings. Hence no need to provide proxy configuration separately. Also, currently, there is no way to provide explicit proxy configuration in MSALPublicClientApplication.